# php i have included a file but cant call functions which are inside class

Tags: php, class, function, include

i have included a file in another file and now i want to use on of the functions from the included file.

when i go to the included file and put a variable there the variable get passed and its all good
 - that means i have includedd the right file.

but when i want to call a funcion which is inside a class

```
class SimpleViewer {
.
.
.
.
function whatever(){}
```

it just doesnt call it when i each it and writes

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function display_gallery_table()...

i know for sure im in the right file because the other values passed but i just can call nothing because its insidfe the class

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to initiate an instance of the class!

Comment: How do you call this function? If it's inside class you need get an instance first.

Comment: You are calling a function from the class, or calling an included function inside the class? If the former, it will need to be a static method, or you'll have to instantiate first.

Answer (score 2):

Try initiating an instance of the class first like this

```
$myClass = new SimpleViewer();
```

then call the function like this

```
$myClass->whatever();
```

Comment: you guys are amazing!!!!!

inside the functions there are varibles how do i call them?

Comment: if they are public, $myClass->myVariable

Comment: you cannot call function variable from outside the function, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = new SimpleViewer();
$var->whatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the object first;

```
$obj = new Class();
$obj->func();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to call a function between classes. The first I know is a static method call. You can call function by defining `class::function()`.

example :

```
public class Parent{
    public static function check(){
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

the static caller may look alike

```
Parent::check()
```

Second way is initiate the class as the new object. From the example we can do the call like

```
$obj = new Parent;
$obj->check();
```

the rest manual of implementing this is on [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)